# Javascript - Cannot read property 'style' of null until I've inspected the div

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to manipulate the text-color of a certain div using javascript.
When trying to run the following code:

`document.getElementById("63b71485db82c3005065f1eabf961985").style.color = "#42f45f";`

I get the error `"Cannot read property 'style' of null"` UNLESS I right-click and inspect the div and then execute the code.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: #1 cause of this sort of problem is the code being placed in the document such that it runs before the target element has been parsed and added to the DOM.

Comment: i bet the element with id `63b71485db82c3005065f1eabf961985` is generated dynamically? It is not present to the dom when you execute the code but it got appended to the DOM afterwards, so the code runs in the console

Comment: @epascarello: I've done the right one now. :-) (BTW, you can fix that as of a fairly recent SO update. You can use the edit link on the list of dupetargets, add in the one you meant, and remove the one you did by mistake.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I need more coffee :)

Comment: The id is not dynamic in the way that it doesn't change from time to time. 
While testing I've just executed from the console. But what you are saying @messerbill seems reasonable since I don't know if the id is present until I inspect the element.